# what are the APIs that support linkedin,twitter and facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

im trying to integrate linkedin,twitter and facebook into my app.Im facing so many problems.Headersearch paths,library paths are not fixed properly.I heard that there are some APIs which support linkedin,twitter and facebook.Can anyone suggest me what are the APIs which support all the three?I tried by using OAuth twitter package and OAuth consumer for limnkedin.
But there is a build error :
Buld Failed:
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I followed these github samples to integrate linkedin and twitter:

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone
https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

Comment: Are you looking for an API, that includes other APIs? Why don't you use the official FB LI TW APIs?

Comment: yes, one API that support linkedin,twitter and facebook

Comment: I tried by using official APIs of linkedin and twitter.But i got a build failed error,as i shown above.I used OAuth for both

Comment: You've set it up wrong then! You probably wont find something which has all the code done for you. Also, the API is the part that is provided by the website (i.e Facebook or Twitter). So you already have that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.
Ref URL: http://getsharekit.com/ 
Hope this helps...